# Getting last 12 characters of uuidv4

Tags: node.js

How do I get the last 12 characters from a uuid?

```js
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
// I am stuck here:
// console.log(uuidv4().substr())
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple `String.substr` use

```js
const s = uuidv4()
console.log(s.substr(s.length - 12))
```